# Onloading webpage spinner (loading) doesn't stop in the browser tab?

Tags: javascript, json, xmlhttprequest

On loading webpage the spinner should stop in browser but it doesn't it keeps on spinning how can I stop this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var requestURL = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=techcrunch&sortBy=top&apiKey=045089075bc74354be01b34f6335d32b";

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

    request.open('GET',requestURL);

    request.responseType = 'json';

    request.send();

    request.onload = function() {
        var myjsondata = request.response;
        console.log(myjsondata);
        showdata(myjsondata);
    }


    function showdata (data) {
            var str = data.articles[0].title;
            document.write(str + "<br> <br>");
            var img = data.articles[1].description;
            document.write(img);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can check this image ->

[image]

Comment: it not spinning in my browser. its working. check your connectivity

Comment: Ok I will check it @Dinesh